# How can we get current controller name in config file of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter, i have some config variables in `config.php` file of codeigniter, but for welcome controller i want to changes its config variable, i am not able to get controller name in config file of codeigniter, i am using this function  `$controller = $this->router->fetch_class();`,  but it is not working can anyone please help me how can we get it ? I have below config variables, but i want to only enable it if controller name is not a welcome

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      =  900; //7200; 900
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 0; //
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = $config['sess_expiration'];
```

Comment: Config is initialized before the router so long story short: you can't.

Comment: why not setting items in controller?

Comment: I can't use this in controller

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to update db schema for ci_session if table not exist, which is in welcome controller